# Getting TypeError: Object(...) is not a function error when trying to change a state property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror, setstate, react-rating

I am very new to React and trying to implement the Rating feature in the code. Can anyone tell, why I am Getting **TypeError: Object(...) is not a function** error when trying to change a state property
when the **Rating** component **onChange** property is set.

My code

```
export default function Details(props) {

const [movie_detail, set_movie_detail] = useState({
    poster_url:"",
    artists:[],
    title:"",
    genres:[],
    duration:0,
    release_date:"",
    rating:0,
    storyline:"",
    id:"",
    wiki_url:"",
    trailer_url:"",
    censor_board_rating:""
  });

    async function data(){
        const data = await fetch(props.baseUrl + "movies/"+props.match.params.id ,
        {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
            }
        });
        const rawData = await data.json();
        set_movie_detail(rawData);
    }

    const handleRatingChange = (value) =>{
        console.log(value);
        setState({rating:value});
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        data();
    }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Header baseUrl={props.baseUrl} movieid={movie_detail.id} ></Header>
        .........

        <div className="column3">
          <Typography>
            <b>Rate this movie</b>
          </Typography>
          <Rating
            name="rating"
            value={movie_detail.rating/2}
            max={5}
            onChange={handleRatingChange}
            icon=
                {
                    <StarBorderIcon 
                    style={{color:"black"}}
                    />
                }
            /> 
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Where does setState come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the correct name of the function that updates the state. In this case `set_movie_detail` instead of `setState`.
You should also merge the update with the previous state instead of overwriting it.

Your function should be as follow:

```
const handleRatingChange = (value) => {
  console.log(value);
  set_movie_detail((prevState) => { ...prevState, rating: value });
}
```

Comment: he should also merge with the previous state, as this is a functional component

Comment: This would remove anyhting else from the state, though.

Comment: I updated my answer to add merging with the previous state instead of overwriting it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `set_movie_detail` instead of `setState` whilst trying to update the state value.

```
const handleRatingChange = (value) =>{
        console.log(value);
        set_movie_detail(prev=>{...prev,rating:value});
}
```

`set_movie_detail` is the function that updates the state of `movie_detail`.
Here, we are making use of the spread operator `...` to ensure that only the desired attribute(s) (`rating` here) is overwritten and the rest of the values remain the same.